# ¿Unidad de medida de la funcion getLength() OpenLayer 5?

Tags: openlayers

Tengo un lineString y quiero saber cuanto mide,use el siguiente código

```
var line = new ol.geom.LineString([latlng1, latlng2]);

    return line.getLength();
```

el método funciona pero no se que medida trae o como formatearlo,me trae un numero así:

0.03120804305123775

la linea es corta de algunos pocos kilometros,necesito saber como formatear este número
la documentacion me dice esto,pero ni idea
 la proyección es 4326 
*getLength (){número}
geom / LineString.js ,
Devuelve la longitud de la cadena lineal en el plano proyectado.*

Answer (score 1):

Deberías utilizar el método **.getLength(geometría, opciones)** de **ol/sphere**. 
Con él obtienes la longitud esférica de una geometría.

En la documentación puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo utilizarlo: https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/measure.html

```
  var formatLength = function(line) {
    var length = getLength(line);
    var output;
    if (length > 100) {
      output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'km';
    } else {
      output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
          ' ' + 'm';
    }
    return output;
  };
```